# Test Action with Target All Threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

When adding [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) with Stop/Stop Now action

You have Target options: All Threads/Current Thread

When choosing Current Thread in a multiple threads environment it stops and don't continue further this Sampler

The problem is that when choosing **All Threads** Some threads execute other sampler after than `Test Action`

It's very confusing, because I expect `All Threads` option to be more strict than just `Current Thread`

In code I saw that in Current Threads it also stop current threads `context.getThread().stop();` and in All Threads option it doesn't.

Is it a bug or a feature (adding grace period of stopping)?

For example Test Plan:

- Thread Group (5 Threads)

  - Sampler1
  - Test Action Target: All Threads, Action Stop/Stop Now
  - Sampler2

Sampler 2 is execute only when Target: All Threads and not when Target: Current Thread

Note: Also choosing Action `Go to next loop iteration` (Target field is disabled) prevent Sampler2 to be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop and Stop Now are different:

- Stop is a clean shutdown, meaning the current running samples will complete. So it is ok if you see other samplers even after test action
- Stop Now is a hard shutdown, meaning current running samples will be interrupted so again, it is ok if you see those other samplers after Test Action

Current thread will only stop the current thread not all thread, so it is ok that:

> When choosing Current Thread in a multiple threads environment it stops and don't continue further this Sampler

All Threads will do action on all threads of test, in code we have:

```
 if (action == STOP_NOW) {
     log.info("Stopping all threads now from element {}", getName());
     context.getEngine().stopTest();
 } else {
     log.info("Stopping all threads from element {}", getName());
     context.getEngine().askThreadsToStop();
 }
```

Regarding your particular case, here is what is happening:

- When you select "**Current Thread**", JMeter immediately stops the current thread as this action is taken into action after the Test Action
- When you select "**All Threads**", JMeter triggers asynchronously a call to all threads shutdown/stop, that's why Sampler2 is called

You may consider this a bug, but I think use case is different.
Still it is now fixed:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61698

Comment: But if I choose All Threads I expect to get more effect than Current Thread, and while Current Thread **always** prevent sending any further request, All Threads option doesn't prevent it

Comment: What options do you select exactly ?

Comment: Target: All Threads, I add test plan hierarchy example to question